# Как обойти header?

Tags: php

Добрый день. У меня есть скрипт, который обрабатывает контент header в рисунок. В итоге переменная picture выводится как рисунок. Кто подскажет, как мне разместить другую часть кода в этом же скрипте? Мне нужно помимо этого рисунка отобразить другие данные, банально - другую текстовую информацию, например echo 'hello' и т.п. 
Или может как вариант, передать $picture в другой файл php, например  script2.php Но как этот сделать?

```
   $fullurl = "https://$server/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=$email_to_get&size=HR648x648"; //sizes defined at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj194329(v=exchg.80).aspx
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM | CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$returned = curl_exec($ch);

$fp = fopen("pic.jpg", 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, $picture);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $picture;
```

Comment: Нужно делать это в другом скрипте, нет?

Comment: И к чему весь этот curl?

Comment: данные берутся по ссылке $fullurl = "https://$server/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=$email_to_get&size=HR648x648";

Comment: подправил сам скрипт. вот полностью скрипт от первой до посл строчки. он обрабатывает данные и выводит картинку.

Comment: Ну вот этот скрипт же в `img[src]` будет подключаться? К чему там другой текст?

Comment: ок. как мне просто вывести здесь же  echo 'hello'; помимо фотографии? допустим ниже фотографии или выше? как разделить эту часть кода? потому что сейчас весь код на странице работает только на преобразование в картинку...

Comment: Так не получится - либо придется выводить всё как HTML со встроенной base64 картинкой и текстом, либо как изображение, оба сразу не получится. На то он и заголовок чтобы определять по нему что за данные получает клиент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынесите весь этот код в отдельный скрипт, например `userlogo.php`

В основном скрипте:

```
<?php
  echo "Before<br/>";
?><img src="userlogo.php"><?php
  echo "After<br/>";
```

Comment: ух ты! сейчас попробую..

Comment: как всё просто. гениально :)